# Is there a way to call a file outside of the public folder from an HTML file inside the public folder?

Tags: html, node.js

Is it possible to access files outside of the public folder from a file in the public folder? I've searched everywhere for the answer and I can't find it. One of the things I'm trying to do here is call a js file in the root of my project from index.html in the public folder using a script tag, and doing something like `<script src="../script.js"></script>` doesn't work. Is there any other way to call the js file (even if it requires calling it from another js file in the public folder called by the html file), or do I have to put the js file in the public folder? This HTML page is being run by node.js, if that makes a difference.

Comment: For static HTML websites: no, there is not. Otherwise any website visitor could just read any file on your webserver's filesystem.

Comment: "I've searched everywhere for the answer and I can't find it" - **pretty sus**

Comment: " or do I have to put the js file in the public folder?" **yes, you do** (well, there is one exception: if your web-server supports the archaic "server-side-includes" system. Apache and IIS both support it but it's disabled by default IIRC). That way you can **inline** the `.js` file directly into the rendered HTML (so just `<script>`, no `src=""` attribute).

Comment: My page is run with Node.js, which is then running the HTML file, does that change anything or can I still not call something outside of the public folder?

Comment: Why didn't you mention NodeJS at all in your post? That's a very important detail...